# SQL select multiple columns to return one distinct field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to return a (single) column that has the distinct values of 4 columns that I will be looking up within the same table.

I've tried

```
"select distinct e1l,e2l,e1s,e2s from jobmovement"
```

but this is just returning each distinct occurrence of the four tables, so for example if there were 4 lines of 178,178,178,178  it would just return 1 of these.

So for example, I have 4 column headers (E1L,E2L,E1S,E2S):

`E1L,E2L,E1S,E2S`

`178,178,178,178
   ,   ,216,216
   ,178,   ,
217,217,178,216`

I would this to return in the single column the distinct values

```
178
216
217
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` to unpivot the data and then use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct v.e
from jobmovement jm cross apply
     (values (jm.e1l), (jm.e2l), (jm.e1s), (jm.e2s)) v(e);
```